# having unwanted space on the right side of my page

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I commented each section in my html and when I commented this section the spacing has gone so I am speculating the cause of this spacing is this section I tried some inspection here in there using dev tools , tried commenting margins in my app still bizarre the spacing persist

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>Contact us</title>

    <!-- local stylesheet file s-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="contactUs.css" />

    <!-- bootsrap style cdn-->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>


    <!--section 2 start-->

    <section class="">
      <div class="section2">
        <div class="row px-5 text-white">
          <div
            class="col-xl-6 col-lg-12 col-md-12 fade-in2 text-white "
          >
            <h2 class="mb-5 fw-bold">GET IN TOUCH</h2>
            <div class="">
              <div class="fs-5">
                <i
                  class="mx-2 fa-solid fa-location-dot iconStyle2 mb-5 display-inline-block"
                ></i>
                <p
                  class="mb-5 mx-2 mx-lg- display-inline-block fs-lg-5 fs-m-6 p-style-s2"
                >
                  333 Middle Winchendon Rd, Rindge NH 03461
                </p>
              </div>

              <div class="fs-5 p2-pad-s2">
                <i
                  class="fa-solid mx-2 fa-mobile-screen-button iconStyle2 mb-5 display-inline-block"
                ></i>
                <div class="display-inline-block">
                  <p class="display-inline-block2 p2-style-s2">125-711-811</p>
                  <p class="f-5 display-inline-block2 fw-medium p2-style-s2">
                    |
                  </p>
                  <p class="display-inline-block2 p2-style-s2">125-668-886</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="fs-5">
                <i
                  class="fa-solid fa-envelope mx-2 mb-5 d-inline-block iconStyle2"
                ></i>
                <p class="display-inline-block p3-style-s2">
                  hello@Empoerfitness.com
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-12 col-m-12 fade-in3">
            <form action="" class="formStyle">
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control input my-3"
                placeholder="name"
              />
              <input
                type="email"
                class="form-control input my-3"
                placeholder="email"
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control input my-3"
                placeholder="subject"
              />
              <textarea
                name=""
                id=""
                cols="30"
                rows="10"
                class="form-control textarea my-3"
                placeholder="message"
              ></textarea>
              <button class="button my-3" type="button">submit</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!--section 2 end -->

    <!--footer start -->

    <footer>
      <div class="footer-container">
        <div class="text-center">
          <div class="fs-3 mx-5 py-2 social-logos">
            <i class="fa-brands fa-square-facebook mx-3 text-white"></i>
            <i class="fa-brands fa-square-x-twitter mx-3 text-white"></i>
            <i class="fa-brands fa-square-instagram mx-3 text-white"></i>
            <i class="fa-brands fa-youtube mx-3 text-white"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col py-2 footer-items">
              <a href="../index.html" class="text-decoration-none mx-2 navItems"
                >Home</a
              >
              <a
                href="../aboutUs/aboutUs.html"
                class="text-decoration-none mx-2 navItems"
                >About us</a
              >
              <a
                href="../services/services.html"
                class="text-decoration-none mx-2 navItems"
                >Services</a
              >

              <a
                href="../contactUs/contactUs.html"
                class="text-decoration-none mx-2 active text-white"
                >Contact us</a
              >
            </div>
          </div>

          <small class="text-white-50 cr-style">
            &copy copyright by Empower Fitness. all rights reserved
          </small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>

    <!--footer end-->

    <!--bootsrap js cdn-->
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <!-- font awesome js -->

    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/bc6916a1d5.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <!-- local js code for observer function-->
    <script defer src="contsctUs.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please punctuate your sentences properly so you're easier to read. Also make it more apparent where the space is that you're describing. The problem isn't clear.

Comment: My wild guess is that there's extra padding outside the columns because you don't have a container element surrounding the row element. See the [grid docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/grid/#example).